# Can we prove that $\operatorname{Tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{Tr}(CBA)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I would like to verify the claim:

> $$\operatorname{Tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{Tr}(CBA)$$

I tried verifying through an example:

Given the following $3$ different matrices:

\begin{align}
A & = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15 & 16
\end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]
B & = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
2 & 4 & 6 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]
C & = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
8 & 7 & 6 & 5 \\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

I calculated $\operatorname{Tr}(ABC) = 7930$ and
$\operatorname{Tr}(CBA) = 7510$.

Is there any thing wrong in my calculation, or does this prove that $\operatorname{Tr}(ABC) \neq \operatorname{Tr}(CBA)$?

Many thanks!

Comment: It's a well known result that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutation: $\mbox{tr}(ABC)=\mbox{tr}(CAB)$, but you have used $CBA$ rather than $CAB$, so there's no reason to expect the trace of $CAB$ to equal the trace of $CBA$.

Comment: I'm sure there will be examples with $2$ by $2$ matrices.

Comment: @Angina It sounds like you're saying that there will be examples with $2$ by $2$ matrices that disprove a true statement, which certainly isn't correct.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, $\mathrm{Tr}\,(ABC)=\mathrm{Tr}\,(CBA)$ cannot hold for all $A$, $B$, $C$ so long as the ring of scalars is nontrivial. For let
\begin{align}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\[2ex]
B &= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\[2ex]
C &= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\[2ex]
\end{align}
Then $ABC = C$, $CBA = 0$, so $\mathrm{Tr}\,(ABC) =  1$, $\mathrm{Tr}\,(CBA)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, the statement $\text{Tr}(ABC)=\text{Tr}(CBA)$ is not true in general, so you should not be concerned that you found a counterexample. Actually, there is a simpler counterexample. Take
$$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
5&2\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix},\:\:\:
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
2&7\\
5&3
\end{bmatrix},\:\:\:
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\text{Tr}(ABC)=49$ while $\text{Tr}(CBA)=61$.